# Serve springdoc swagger-ui in subdirectory nginx

Tags: spring, spring-boot, nginx, swagger-ui, springdoc

I have read the docs about how to serve springdoc behind a reverse proxy (https://springdoc.org/index.html#how-can-i-deploy-springdoc-openapi-ui-behind-a-reverse-proxy) and also checked all of the questions about the topic but still having a problem.

I'm serving a spring-boot (2.6.2 version) application in a subdirectory with nginx:

```
location /subdirectory/ {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_buffer_size 128k;
                proxy_buffers 4 256k;
                proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;

                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Prefix "/subdirectory/";
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_x_forwarded_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol https;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
                proxy_set_header X-Url-Scheme https;
        }
```

I have also configured Spring Boot as per docs:

**application.properties:**

```
server.forward-headers-strategy=framework
server.tomcat.redirect-context-root=false
```

When I visit my domain for a normal request to the Spring Boot API works fine, e.g.:

```
GET https://example.com/subdirectory/countries - OK 200 Returns the expected JSON
```

But when I try to visit the springdoc swagger-ui with:

```
GET https://example.com/subdirectory/swagger-ui/index.html - OK 200
```

**I get a 200 OK but the .css and .js files requests return 404.** I see a blank page and nothing about swagger. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing forwarding filter.

```
@Bean
ForwardedHeaderFilter forwardedHeaderFilter() {
   return new ForwardedHeaderFilter();
}
```